# Oracle SQL: Using CHR() function with || concatenate

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to concatenate characters with output of query:

Query:

```
select 'Text: '||chr(39)||wfn.notification_id||chr(39) 
from wf_notification wfn;
```

Error:

> ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here

How can I use concatenate || and chr() in same query?

Comment: To answer your question: yes, you can.

Comment: Exactly as you did. Is this your query, or is this just where you think the error comes from? (It almost surely doesn't come from the code you posted here.)

Comment: What is the data type of `wf_notification.notification_id`? If it is a user-defined type then that might be the source of your error.

Comment: As Sudipta points out, the table appears to belong to an application called Oracle E-Business Suite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `||` exactly as you did. Demo below. That error must come from some other part of your query.

```
select 'Text: '||chr(39)||ename||chr(39) from scottemp;

'TEXT:'||CHR(39)||ENAME||CHR(39)
--------------------------------
Text: 'SMITH'
Text: 'ALLEN'
Text: 'WARD'
Text: 'JONES'
Text: 'MARTIN'
Text: 'BLAKE'
Text: 'CLARK'
Text: 'SCOTT'
Text: 'KING'
Text: 'TURNER'
Text: 'ADAMS'
Text: 'JAMES'
Text: 'FORD'
Text: 'MILLER'
```

Comment: Your suggestion did work for me.  Issue is with joining two tables.

Here's the original query
      select 'mailto:'|| fscp.parameter_value || '?subject=' ||  wfn.subject nid_subject || chr(38)       
      from apps.wf_notifications wfn, apps.fnd_svc_comp_param_vals_v fscp
      where fscp.component_id = '10012' and component_parameter_id = '10189'
      and wfn.item_key = ':itemkey';

Comment: As the answer suggests, your select clause looks okay.  Can you provide more information about the tables/views you are joining?  Also, your last line uses ':itemkey';  Is this supposed to be a bind variable?  If so, lose the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is what you want to do.

```
select 'Text: '||chr(39)||wfn.notification_id||chr(39) 
from wf_notifications wfn; -- 's' is missing from the table name.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what piece of data in the question gives you a clue that the table name is wrong?

Comment: probably, @g33k should have tagged it with oracle-e-business-suite.

Comment: You're right, Sudipta.  The table name was incorrect but not the issue I was facing.  I simplified the query for this question.  Your query does work.  I had to create a new question on stackoverflow.