# Oracle SQL: Using CHR() function with || concatenate and join

Tags: sql, oracle

Query below returns error

```
SELECT 'mailto:'|| fscp.parameter_value || '?subject=' || wfn.subject nid_subject || chr(38)       
FROM apps.wf_notifications wfn, apps.fnd_svc_comp_param_vals_v fscp
WHERE fscp.component_id = :component_id 
AND component_parameter_id = :param
AND wfn.item_key = :itemkey;
```

Error

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 
>   00923.00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

When I remove the '|| chr(38)' at the end of the select statement, the query runs fine.
Something related to joining tables?  Because the below query also works fine:

```
select 'Text: '||chr(39)||wfn.notification_id||chr(39) from wf_notifications wfn;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Using CHR() function with || concatenate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907304/oracle-sql-using-chr-function-with-concatenate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this in the `select`:

```
|| wfn.subject nid_subject ||
```

Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT 'mailto:'|| fscp.parameter_value || '?subject=' || wfn.subject || nid_subject || chr(38)   
----------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Alex is right.  The key in the question is that it works without `chr(38)`.  So, try this:

```
SELECT ('mailto:'|| fscp.parameter_value || '?subject=' || wfn.subject || chr(38) ) as nid_subject
```

Notice the use of parentheses and `as` to make it clear that a column alias is being defined.

Comment: I suspect `nid_subject` was supposed to be an alias for the entire expression, rather than another column - partly because it has no table (alias) prefix. But hard to tell...

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . You are right.  There is even a hint in the question.